# CLI options do not work if passed at the end of command

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

In brief: `ls -a /tmp` works but `ls /tmp -a` does not.

I recently started using Macbook Pro.
Coming from a Linux background, command like `ls /tmp -a` seems perfectly fine to me.

But for some reason these do not work in the same fashion in Mac. Argument flags are not recognised if they are specified at the end after the path.

Here is a demo:

```
/tmp/demo  ➜ ls -a ./
.           ..          .hidden-bar foo
/tmp/demo  ➜ ls ./ -a
ls: -a: No such file or directory
./:
foo
/tmp/demo  ➜
```

I am using latest `zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)`

I can see similar behaviour of several other commands like `du`, `rm` etc. Almost all such are in /bin folder. I wonder if it has something to do with UNIX and Linux differences.

Does anybody know the reason behind the difference and if possible a fix for it?

Comment: Your original question/statement mentions *arguments* but you're actually asking about placing *options* at the end of a command line ;-)

Comment: OSX was spawned off of, I think, FreeBSD, while Linux uses GNU tools. I'm surprised that GNU tools allow options to follow arguments. I'd recommend you retrain your brain and get used to the BSD fashion.

Answer (score 1):

This is because apple `zsh` shell version. To install `zsh` version with that behaviour, you have to install [homebrew](http://brew.sh). You can easily to it by typing the following:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Once installed, install the `zsh` formulae:

```
brew install zsh
```

Then you have to replace your shell with `zsh` provided by homebrew:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

After that you should be able to test your `zsh` version and use command arguments like you want.

Comment: That is what I used in the first place. I digged a little deeper for you - they also use zsh.org for downloads. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/78e9ae8c49ed74f17433d5aab10c2f8949c1392b/Library/Formula/zsh.rb#L6